# How to add a dynamic links above banner in wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I need to add some links with image above my banner which must be editable by admin in wordpress.

See the attached design:

![wp] https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/aCt9W7KPY80RZbyRM2rvGvvsUGvR1KxUcrEh6t2LzGjum9KnNTQAvu7EQOl3fCIyNQyRb1vKn9U

How can i do this? I need to use plugin.?

Comment: I need to do the same on my sidebar and above my footer, will creating menu works?

Comment: The attachment is broken. Could you please repost it?

Answer (score 0):

You can put this html code in custome widgets and call the custom widgest wherever you want to use and admin will easily able to change the link from widgest area in admin panel.

Comment: Bad practice...what if theme does not support widgets??..what OP is looking for `theme options`

Comment: I do agree with you @swapnesh but most of the themes support widgets. widgets are the core part of wordpress cms, i think you know about this very well.

Comment: Is he developing on the core theme ?? I guess not :)

Comment: NO, i am making it on Hades :)

Answer (score 0):

I have acheived this by creating another menu  and then using image plugin for menu.